# How to print with inline if statement?

Tags: python, dynamic, printing, inline

This dictionary corresponds with numbered nodes:

```
{0: True, 1: True, 2: True, 3: False, 4: False, 5: False, 6: True, 7: True, 8: False, 9: False}
```

Using two print statements, I want to print marked and unmarked nodes as follows:

- Marked nodes: `0 1 2 6 7`
- Unmarked nodes: `3 4 5 8 9`

I want something close to:

```
print("Marked nodes: %d" key in markedDict if markedDict[key] = True)
print("Unmarked nodes: %d" key in markedDict if markedDict[key] = False)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
nodes = {0: True, 1: True, 2: True,
         3: False, 4: False, 5: False,
         6: True, 7: True, 8: False, 9: False}

print("Marked nodes: ", *[i for i, value in nodes.items() if value])
print("Unmarked nodes: ", *[i for i, value in nodes.items() if not value])
```

**Output:**

```
Marked nodes:  0 1 2 6 7
Unmarked nodes:  3 4 5 8 9
```

Comment: you can just do if value and if not value

Comment: Works with Python 3.4.0, too.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution that works with versions of python which do not support the unpacking syntax used in the top answer yet. Let `d` be your dictionary:

```
>>> print('marked nodes: ' + ' '.join(str(x) for x,y in d.items() if y))
marked nodes: 0 1 2 6 7
>>> print('unmarked nodes: ' + ' '.join(str(x) for x,y in d.items() if not y))
unmarked nodes: 3 4 5 8 9
```

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid duplicate iteration over dictionary.

```
marked = []
unmarked = []
mappend = marked.append
unmappend = unmarked.append
[mappend(str(x))if y else unmappend(str(x)) for x, y in d.iteritems()]
print "Marked - %s\r\nUnmarked - %s" %(' '. join(marked), ' '. join(unmarked))
```